# Copy only the text until special character on every line into another file

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have a text file which contains the following data:

```
ChainCtrlBuildChain() : ChainController.c
ChainCtrlDumpChain() : ChainController.c
ChainCtrlDumpChanCallback() : ChainController.c
ChainCtrlExit() : ChainController.c
ChainCtrlGetBitStreamChan() : ChainController.c
ChainCtrlInit() : ChainController.c
```

I want to copy only the function names into another text file.

My desired output:

```
ChainCtrlBuildChain
ChainCtrlDumpChain
ChainCtrlDumpChanCallback
ChainCtrlExit
ChainCtrlGetBitStreamChan
ChainCtrlInit
```

How can I do it?

Note that the function names and class names will be different depending on user input.

---

By using [user4035's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17941416/1743811),

```
$text =~ s/\s:\s.*//g;
```

I got "()" outside function body like

```
ChainCtrlBuildChain()
ChainCtrlDumpChain()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you only text processing part. I think, you can do the file I/O yourself.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $text = qq{ChainCtrlBuildChain() : ChainController.c
ChainCtrlDumpChain() : ChainController.c
ChainCtrlDumpChanCallback() : ChainController.c
ChainCtrlExit() : ChainController.c
ChainCtrlGetBitStreamChan() : ChainController.c
ChainCtrlInit() : ChainController.c};

$text =~ s/\s:\s.*//g;
print $text;
```

Prints:

```
ChainCtrlBuildChain()
ChainCtrlDumpChain()
ChainCtrlDumpChanCallback()
ChainCtrlExit()
ChainCtrlGetBitStreamChan()
ChainCtrlInit()
```

Comment: It works. Thanks.I did the I/O myself. I am new to perl so i didn't understand this line "$text =~ s/\s:\s.*//g;".  But i will google it and try to figure it out.

Comment: @user2628315 Search for regular expressions tutorial in Perl. This line replaces [space][:][space][anything up to the end of line] to and empty string